# How to set up nested acl rules in HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy, rules

I serve multiple services from my domain using the same HAProxy instance, at `domain.com/s1/` and `domain.com/s2/` . I would like to do some operations (including ACL matching) only when certain conditions are met *within* `s2`. Using `acl`'s like

```
acl service_1         path_beg   /s1/
acl service_2         path_beg   /s2/
acl service_1_path_1  path_beg   /s2/path1/
acl service_1_path_2  path_beg   /s2/path2/
```

will lead to *all* requests being matches for the `s2/path1/` and `/s2/path2/` patterns, which is wasteful if I know that the vast majority of requests are for `s1`.

Is there a way that I can say "evaluate for the `path_1` or `path_2` patterns only if the acl `service_2` matches"?

Note that this is not a case of wanting to `AND` two conditions; I want the second `acl` to not even be computed unless the first one matches. Is that even possible in HAProxy?

Answer (score 1):

**HAProxy Multiple Condition Example**

Here is one example I use:

```
acl bot_ok path_end txt
acl bot_ok url_reg ^/$
acl derpy3 hdr_sub(user-agent) -i bash curl wget slack
acl derpy3 req.ver !1.1
http-request silent-drop if derpy3 !bot_ok
```

Let the bots in and/or use http protocols other than 1.1 **IF** they hit `/` or `.txt` files.

We define multiple acl's, then set the condition and/or negating condition on the action.

Comment: Thanks; I have something similar to that as well, but I do not even want `bot_ok` to be computed unless `derpy3` evaluates to true.